# Posts not showing with custom categorybase and subcategories

Tags: customization

Edit: Fixed. I had an error in my permlink structure.

I have a problem with individual posts not showing with their URL.

I have set a custom category base in Permlinks called 'story'.
I have a blogpost category called 'chapters', which has a subcategory 'chapter-1'.

Both category pages show fine, but when I want to go to the post (I have to, because I'm using the read more link) I get a 404 error, it can not find the post.

The post does show on the category pages, but the actual link, which wordpress creates as: site.com/story/chapters/chapter-1/post-name/ doesn't work. It looks good to me, that's how I want the URL structure to be.

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your Permalink Settings should be:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

if you set it to subcategory only then you will have what you desire:

/category/sub-category/postname/

Comment: That's what I have, indeed. But it's not working. The correct and desired URL is being created for the post, but the post is not there/404.

Comment: Can you share the link to your site?